# Extensionless MVC and IIS 8 request filtering

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, iis, webserver

I am using IIS 8 on Server 2012 and have an MVC website serving extensionless pages. I'm trying to harden IIS by blocking all but an allowed set of extensions in the request filtering section. As extensionless MVC pages have no extension, this is proving somewhat difficult!

I've tried adding `.mvc`, `.aspx` and `.cshtml` to the allowed list to see if any of those would work but by unticking `Allow unlisted file name extensions` in the `Edit Feature Settings` menu, I keep getting a 404 error.

Is there any combination of special characters or some kind of keyword I can use to add extensionless addresses to the allowed list so that I can block all unlisted extensions? I really dont want to have to allow unlisted file name extensions and then create a list of hundreds of denied extensions.

Cheers all!

Comment: Is [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26203202/3345644) helpful? If so feel free to accept and/or upvote ше if, or provide a feedback so I could improve it. Otherwise this thread looks abandoned and kinda useless for further readers. Thank you!

Answer (score 12):

Sure. To allow extensionless adresses, add `<add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />` to your web.config as below:

```
  <system.webServer>
    <security>
      <requestFiltering>
        <fileExtensions allowUnlisted="false">
          <add fileExtension="." allowed="true" />
        </fileExtensions>
      </requestFiltering>
    </security>
  </system.webServer>
```

Let me know if this helped.